# "Not Connected" message in Visual Studio 2010 when using TFS

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, tfs, embedded-resource

In Visual Studio 2010 Premium I have a project that is connected to TFS. Sometimes I see "not connected" messages on the tabs of individual files when open in VS2010.  All TFS related functionality (i.e. "Check Out For Edit") seems to be working correctly.

Here's a screen snippet from a VS2010 Winforms project to show what I'm talking about:

[LM_Master_Data.sql - not connnected http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ac423cf1cf.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ac423cf1cf.png)

This is a SQL script that is in my project with a "Build Action" of "Embedded Resource" (in case that matters some how to TFS).

I've searched with Google to see if anyone else has this problem but so far no luck.

So, the question is:

What does this mean and what should I do about it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this message means that the SQL script is not associated with an open database (e.g. not connected to the database).  I don't think it has anything to do with being connected to TFS.